# How to create a new customer via code

Tags: acumatica

Hello how do I add a new customer with a default contact in my process in code behind.

So far I have this but I need to create a contact object link the two somehow.

```
            PX.Objects.AR.Customer m = new PX.Objects.AR.Customer();

            m.AcctCD = "Test1";
            m.AcctName = "Joe Bloggs";
            m.Type = "CU";

            Customers.Insert(m);

            Persist();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        CustomerMaint graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<CustomerMaint>();

        Customer cust = new Customer();
        cust.AcctName = "Company Name";
        cust = (Customer)graph.CurrentCustomer.Insert(cust);

        Address addr = (Address)graph.Addresses.Current;
        addr.AddressLine1 = "Address 1";
        addr.AddressLine2 = "Address 2";
        addr.City = "City";
        addr.State = "State";
        addr.PostalCode = "Zip";
        addr.CountryID = "Country";
        graph.Addresses.Update(addr);

        Contact contact = (Contact)graph.DefContact.Current;
        contact.ContactType = ContactTypesAttribute.BAccountProperty;
        contact.FirstName = "FirstName";
        contact.LastName = "Last Name";
        contact.EMail = "emaiL@email.com";
        contact.WebSite = "www.website.com";
        contact.Phone1 = "1234567890";
        contact.Fax = "1234567890";
        graph.DefContact.Update(contact);


        graph.Actions.PressSave();
```

Answer (score 1):

This what I did seems to work good. Got instance of the customermaint graph. Insert new Customer into currentcustomer and edit current def contact.

```
            PX.Objects.AR.CustomerMaint graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<PX.Objects.AR.CustomerMaint>();

            PX.Objects.AR.Customer m = new PX.Objects.AR.Customer();

            m.AcctCD = "Test4";
            m.AcctName = "Jo Bloggs";
            m.Type = "CU";

            graph.CurrentCustomer.Insert(m);

            PX.Objects.CR.Contact c = graph.DefContact.Current;

            c.ContactType = "AP";
            c.FullName = "Joe Bloggs";
            c.EMail = "joe@Bloggs.com";

            graph.Actions.PressSave();
```